# Unable download image file in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Iam trying to download image using angularjs. In postman im getting the output as this format:

锟斤拷锟斤拷JFIF,,锟斤拷xPhotoshop 3.08BIM\gP53616c7465645f5fdfdda5a4f94df34e8d1d8e056e7e5dcc820ce57f793e13bfa39119fdc1b0c079锟斤拷C锟斤拷�锟�锟�锟�锟�锟�锟�锟�锟�锟�锟�锟�锟�锟�锟�锟�锟�锟

```
<a id="download" ng-click="downloadfile()">Download FileName</a>
```

This code for downloading the image.

```
$scope.downloadfile=function(){
var download = document.getElementById("download");
$scope.downloadData =  锟斤拷锟斤拷JFIF,,锟斤拷xPhotoshop 3.08BIM\gP53616c7465645f5fdfdda5a4f94df34e8d1d8e056e7e5dcc820ce57f793e13bfa39119fdc1b0c079锟斤拷C锟斤拷�锟�锟�锟�锟�锟�锟�锟�锟�锟�锟�锟�锟�锟�锟�锟�锟�锟;

download.onclick = function() {

  downloadFile("text.jpg", $scope.downloadData);
}

function downloadFile(filename, text) {
  var pom = document.createElement('a');
  pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:image/jpeg;charset-utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  pom.setAttribute('download', filename);
  pom.click();
}
}
```

When i download a image i will get invalid image
Thanks in advance

Comment: When Interceptor is off image preview works fine. Otherwise it will show raw data

Comment: I want to know the format is correct

Comment: Just try pasting the output of 'data:image/jpeg;charset-utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text) in chrome address bar, if it displays the image correctly then the issue will not be with the format

Comment: @Kailas In chrome image is not displaying. So format is wrong.